# Alternative to Thread.Suspend() method

Tags: c#, multithreading, suspend

`Thread.Suspend()` method is obsolete as you know. I want to suspend thread immidiately when button click event comes. I used Thread.Suspend() and it works perfect but everyone suggest that using Thread.Suspend() method is not a good method to suspend the task. I used a flag to suspend the task but every time when a button click event comes, i have to wait to exit from task. I used Thread.IsAlive flag to wait the thread to exit but this method freezes form.

```
void ButtonClickEvent(object sender, ButtonClickEventArgs e)
{
    TheadExitFlag = false;

    if(MyThread != null)
    {
        while(MyThread.IsAlive);
        //MyThread.Suspend();
    }
}

void MyTask(void)
{
    while(TheadExitFlag)
    {
        // some process
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

How can i suspend the thread immidiately?

Comment: Please be more clear about what you want to do - I'm not even 100% sure if you want to 'suspend' the thread or exit the thread.  Another example: is ` MyThread` a reference to the thread that `MyTask` is running on?  It seems like `ThreadExitFlag == true` means that the thread should *not* exit; if so, I suggest you change the name.

Comment: Why do you want to suspend the thread?

Comment: I would bet that you're trying to solve a problem using wrong facilities, why you need to suspend a thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no alternative with the same functionality, AFAIK. I am not sure if the problems with an OS `Suspend()` could be worked around within the language/libraries, but no attempt has been made to do so, so maybe it's too difficult or even sensibly impossible.

Until such an alernative exists, you are reduced to polling for a suspend flag and then waiting on some synchronization object for a 'resume' signal. I have used [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `ManualResetEvent` to toggle between a running and idle state.

```
ManualResetEvent run = new ManualResetEvent(true);

void ResumeButton_Click(object sender, ButtonClickEventArgs e)
{
  run.Set();
  PauseButton.Enabled = true;
  ResumeButton.Enabled = false;
}

void PauseButton_Click(object sender, ButtonClickEventArgs e)
{
  run.Reset();
  PauseButton.Enabled = false;
  ResumeButton.Enabled = true;
}

void MyTask(void)
{
    while (run.WaitOne())  // Wait for the run signal.
    {
      // Do work here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an approximate solution to this problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45786529/3013473 using AspectJ and wait/notify.