# Alternative to Thread.suspend() and .resume()

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a large segment of code that is not a loop, just a list of commands that happens once but takes some time. I need it to either pause or terminate this at any point based on a changing boolean value. I could use a different thread to suspend, resume and stop this code, but those methods are deprecated, so I would like to avoid using them. I could check the boolean between every line of code, but I am hoping for a more elegant solution. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: How are you executing each command?  If that is separate class like "Action" or "Command" you could perform the check there.  Other than that not much you can do...as written in other answers.

Comment: I am code autonomous for a FRC robot. Some of it is to set motors to a speed and wait, other bits are to set motor values until sensors give certain valuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to handle interrupting a thread (in this case, to pause or stop it) is, naturally, with `Thread#interrupt()`. It is designed so that you can define safe points at which the thread can be interrupted, which for you is naturally the point between each task. So, to avoid having to manually check your variable between each task, and to be able to easily resume where you left off, you can store your tasks as a list of `Runnable`s, and remember your position in the list from when you left off, like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void runTask(Runnable task) throws InterruptedException {
        task.run();
        if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
    }
    Runnable[] frobnicateTasks = new Runnable[] {
        () -> { System.out.println("task1"); },
        () -> { Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); }, //Interrupt self only as example
        () -> { System.out.println("task2"); }
    };
    public int frobnicate() {
        return resumeFrobnicate(0);
    }
    public int resumeFrobnicate(int taskPos) {
        try {
            while (taskPos < frobnicateTasks.length)
                runTask(frobnicateTasks[taskPos++]);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        if (taskPos == frobnicateTasks.length) {
            return -1; //done
        }
        return taskPos;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        int progress = foo.frobnicate();
        while (progress != -1) {
            System.out.println("Paused");
            progress = foo.resumeFrobnicate(progress);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
-->
task1
Paused
task2
Done
```

Comment: I disagree with this.  Interrupt has the problem that it will ... basically ... interrupt some blocking operations, leaving the interrupted thread in a state where resumption is (at least) complicated.  Testing a boolean is a better approach for a pause / resume.

Comment: @StephenC All blocking operations that might be interrupted force you to check for InterruptedException and decide what to do. It sounds to me like if they are using any such operations, then interrupting them is the desired behavior (though they may need to add some means of signaling to not increment taskPos); if this is not the desired behavior then they can easily replace `Thread.interrupted()` with a special field query.

Comment: In this case, the OP wants suspend / resume, not interrupt / start-over-again semantics.  The Question says that he is looking for a replacement for `Thread.suspend()`, etcetera.

Comment: I like this solution as it overcomes the problems that may arise when suspending/pausing a task inbetween (e.g. think of a sort algorithm that is paused and in the meantime the underlying list is changed) by falling back to the last well-defined state. Of course this might cause other problems especially when the interrupted task has already performed some state changes that should better be undone. So a task might decide to not react to interruption in case undoing changes are too complex. It has full control! Much better than using the deprecated Thread-methods!

Answer (score 7):

> I could check the boolean between every line of code, but I am hoping for a more elegant solution.  Is there a good way to do this?

Unfortunately, no.

To replace pause / resume, what you really need is for one thread to "pause" another thread, without involving the code of the second thread.

This is not possible to do safely in Java as currently spec'd and implemented.

The deprecated Thread methods are the only way for one thread to kill, stop / pause, resume another thread ... if the other thread is not actively cooperating.  They were deprecated because (in a nutshell) that kind of control *cannot* be implemented safely within any current generation mainstream JVM<sup>1</sup>.

The best you could do is wrap the pause / resume logic in a method that the second thread calls at appropriate points.  (This probably should use wait / notify ... or equivalent ... to deal with the resumption.  But wait/notify *per se* does not address your clear requirement for pause/resuming a non-cooperating thread.)

---

<sup>1 - You'd need something like the Isolates API to do this. There have been attempts to implement it in research projects, but AFAIK Isolates has never been implemented in a production JVM.</sup>

Comment: There is an approximate solution to this problem. Please see the answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922040/alternative-to-thread-suspend-and-resume/45786529#45786529

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent documentation about why `Thread.stop()`, `Thread.pause()` and `Thread.resume()` are deprecated:

[Java Thread Primitive Deprecation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

There is also an alternative for `Thread.pause()` / `Thread.resume()` using `wait` and `notify` explained.

Comment: I cannot think of how to use wait and notify in my situation. If you can, I would be glad to know.

Comment: @yesennes See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922040/alternative-to-thread-suspend-and-resume/45786529#45786529 for doing this using wait/notify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wait / notify as a alternative to suspend / resume. Instead of stop you can set a flag, notify and throw an exception from notified thread

Comment: Remember this is not a looped bit of code. There is not convenient place where checking a flag will happen often. If I understand your solution, I would have check the flag every other line, at which point I might as well just check the boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea how to do this using AspectJ. The solution I am outlining below will allow you to pause/resume another thread. This pause will only come into effect on the next method invocation from inside of your target method after you called the pause routine. This will *not* require boolean checks after every line of code of your target method. I am using wait/notify to do this.

I am using Spring in the below example.

First, wrap your target method in a Runnable.

```
   package com.app.inter.thread.communication.runnables;


    public class TestRunnable implements Runnable{

        public void run() {
            long i=0;
            //For explanatory purposes, I have used an infinite loop below
            //and printed an increasing number

            while(!Thread.interrupted()){
                //someService.action1();
                //someService.action2();
                //....                    
                if(i++%10000000==0)
                    System.out.println("Working "+i);
            }

        }

    }
```

Next, you make an aspect which would be called conditionally on any method invocation inside your target method.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class HandlerAspect {

    public static volatile boolean stop=false;
    public static volatile String monitor="";



    @Pointcut("withincode(public void com.app.inter.thread.communication.runnables.TestRunnable.run()) "
            + "&& call(* *.*(*)) "
            + "&& if()")
    public static boolean stopAspect(){
        return stop;
    }
    @Before("stopAspect()") 
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint jp) {
       try {
           System.out.println("Waiting");

           synchronized(monitor){
               monitor.wait();
           }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stop=false;
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you want to pause your thread, just set the value of `stop` to true, and vice versa.

```
@Service
public class Driver {
    @Autowired
    private HandlerAspect aspect;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=-1;
        TestRunnable runnable = new TestRunnable();
        Thread thread= new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        aspect.monitor="MONITOR";
        while((i=scanner.nextInt())!=0){
            switch(i){
                case 1: 
                    aspect.stop=true;
                    break;      
                case 2:

                    aspect.stop=false;                  
                    synchronized(aspect.monitor){
                        aspect.monitor.notify();
                    }
                    break;  
            }
        }
        // in case the main thread is stopped
        // while the other thread is in wait state
        synchronized(aspect.monitor){
            aspect.monitor.notify();
        }
        thread.interrupt();

    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
...
Working 400000001
1Working 410000001
Working 420000001
Working 430000001
Working 440000001
Working 450000001
Working 460000001
Working 470000001
Waiting
2
Working 480000001
Working 490000001
0
```

Working code is at https://github.com/zafar142007/InterThreadCommunication

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why no one mentioned semaphore here. You can every once in a while try acquire and release a semaphore in you main code. On the side work you can trigger semaphore acquire so to block the main code acquiring if you don't want the whole while loop with wait and notify going.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this thread still seems to be active, so I will pitch my answer, as 4 years of developing experience has given me more insight and hasn't quite clouded my memory of my problem.

The problem boiled down to the FRC library I was using trying to shoehorn me into use functions that were roughly like: `motor.drive(speed, time)` and would block execution for time length. In all but the most narrow cases, this is bad function to use, as so much of robotics code relies on combining sensor data and time passing to make decisions.

What I should have done was call it with time being 0 or very small, or find some other function that would indefinitely drive the motor, and be sure to turn it off afterwards. Then run that function in a tight loop looking for the conditions that would make be go to the next command.

I probably should have used a state machine to make the code more readable and easier to modify.